no documents matching ui_textfinder.h could be found
I have installed qt 6.7.2 on macos (from installer), and am now trying out the simple tutorial for TextFinder. I have completed the instructions upto step-8, ie added the widgets in the Designer. Now in step-9, when I am trying to add goto-Slot in FindButton, I am getting the error: "No documents matching "ui_textfinder.h" could be found. Rebuilding the project might help."
This file (ui_textfinder.h) does not exist, instead I have a file named "textfinder.h". The instructions also say that the slot will be added in the file "textfinder.h". I tried making a symbolic link ui_textfinder.h linked to the existing textfinder.h, but that does not help - I am still getting the same error. I also tried rescanning the project, that is also not helping, even though now the ui_textfinder.h file is seen in the file system tab in the QtCreator.
How do I fix this problem? The error says I might rebuild the project, but the files are not yet fully created, so is that going to help?
(Note: this error does not come up when I install qt with homebrew. It shows up only when I install with qt-installer - qt-online-installer-macOS-x64-4.8.0.dmg, downloaded from qt website.)
I see that another person had raised a similar complaint. But the answer given there is not clear to me. Also, that is an old question, so that might have referred to some other version of qt.

Files named as ui_something.h are normally generated based on the project configuration or upon manual usage of the uic program. Are you actually using an ui file created with Qt Designer? If so, did you check the Designer manual?

I noticed that when I install qt with installer, the included file is "./ui_textfinder.h" (and it cannot find this file), but when I install through brew the name is "ui_textfinder.h" (this does not report error). I have no clue why this difference exists between the 2 versions.
